# How to write a value to Excel named range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I created a named range one column width "MyRange1" that is some full length column. This column is partly filled with values.

In VBA I have a variable "Last_Row" with row number of the first empty cell of the column "MyRange1".

Please just how can I write some value "TestValue1" to that cell in VBA procedure?

I use Cells... Range... and always get errors. Are the named ranges visible from VBA?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code and explain what it did wrong.

Comment: `Range("MyRange1").Column` will give you the column number

Comment: `Range("MyRange1").Cells(Last_Row).Value = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Range("MyRange1").Cells(Last_Row).Value
= "Thank you, Tim Williams "